# `as` + objdump skips custom section when assembling + disassembling

Tags: assembly, disassembly, gnu-assembler, objdump

I have the following file:

`test.s`

```
.section a_random_section

label_number1:
    jmp label_number1
```

and after executing `as -o test.o test.s && objdump -d test.o` I'm getting the following output:

```
test.o:     file format elf64-x86-64
```

but I'd expect to get something like this:

```
test.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section a_random_section:

0000000000000000 <label_number1>:
   0:   eb fe                   jmp    0 <label_number1>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The section is still there in the binary but `-d` only disassembles executable sections. You created a custom section with default attributes which does not make it executable. Either make it executable or use `-D` (capital) to disassemble all sections.

Comment: Oh god... what a mistake from me.... thank you for your answer! Could you (@Jester) please write your comment as an answer, so I can mark this question as answered? Thanks!